# Ninject - What is the correct way to set up bindings in the domain model layer of an N-Tier MVC3 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

I've started using Ninject in an ASP.NET MVC 3 project, using the standard boot strapper that comes with the nuget package, as below.

```
/// <summary>
    /// Load your modules or register your services here!
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
           // Documentation for setting up Ninject in ASP.NET MVC3 app: 
           // https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/Setting-up-an-MVC3-application

           // Add bindings here. No modules required unless we need to add in further
           // separation of concerns.

           kernel.Bind<ISessionManager>().To<SessionManager>();
           kernel.Bind<ICookieManager>().To<CookieManager>();
           kernel.Bind<ILogManager>().To<LogManager>();
           kernel.Bind<IStringOutput>().To<StringOutput>();
    }
```

**Within my Domain Model layer**, there is a class called `CookieManager`. Within my `CookieManager` class, I'm using a class called `SecureObjectSerializer`.

I want to use dependency injection so that the `CookieManager` is not tighly bound to the `SecureObjectSerializer`.

**I don't want the MVC project to have to know about the SecureObjectSerializer, setting up the bindings etc.** That seems to be taking DI too far to me.

I do however, think that within the Domain Model layer, the CookieManager should have SecureObjectSerializer passed in in a DI manner.

My questions:

1. To have the binding registered in the Domain Model layer, should I create a Ninject bootstrapper within the Domain Model layer? If so, how should I have this triggered. Would I supply a hook and call something like `DomainModel.BindModelDependencies(kernel);` in the MVC project.
2. When it's time to resolve a new instance of an object, what would this code look like? It's kind of hidden when using the MVC bootstrapper?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should put a NinjectModule inside of the domain assembly (not the web assembly) and you can tell ninject to scan your domain assembly and look for the module. module is just a class that inherits from NinjectModule base class and implements Load(). This way the web project only needs a reference to the domain project. the Scanning should look something like:

either of these two: (actually there are a few more options but these are the main ones i use)

```
var assemblysToScan = "Assembly.*";
var assemblysToScan = new[] { "Assembly.Domain", "Assembly.Web" };
```

and then just

```
kernel.Scan(x =>
                {
                    x.From(assemblysToScan)
                    x.AutoLoadModules();
                });
```

When you want to resolve an object, just put it as a ctor argument, and if ninject is managing you objects, it will inject the type (based on the bindings you have configured) automatically.

EDIT:

add references to ninjectcommonservicelocator (cant remember the exact name) & microsoft.practices.servicelocation

in your bootstrapper add these:

```
using Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation;
using CommonServiceLocator.NinjectAdapter;

var locator = new NinjectServiceLocator(kernel);
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => locator);
```

then in your class:

```
using Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation;

class CookieManager : ICookieManager
{
  SecureObjectSerialiser secureObjectSerialiser;

  CookieManager()
  {
    this.secureObjectSerialiser = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<SecureObjectSerialiser>();
  }
}
```

the reason for the microsoft.practices locator is your code should not know that ninject is working under the covers. instead, you use a generic servicelocator that can be reused if you change containers.

personally i would avoid this and just inject everything. but if you cant, you cant.

Comment: Thanks. " just put it as a ctor argument" - Where? In MVC this works fine, but what about when I want to create an instance of an object outside of the MVC project. Could you provide a more verbose code example?

Comment: and if you mean your domain code, where is the code being executed from?

Comment: I mean in the domain model code. Ultimately, it will be executed from the MVC layer, but I need to limit the number of dependencies that I'm injecting from that layer, so as to create a clean API. So the MVC layer just uses ICookieManager, and doesn't have to inject SecureObjectSerializer.

Comment: Which I'm assuming requires use of some sort of resolver in the domain model layer. Hope this makes sense, thanks.

Comment: That's what I was after thanks. I will mark as answer, as it is the answer to my question, but I'm not sure this is the best approach for my project. I need to review this article on service locators as an antipattern http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx. For now I think i'll go DI by hand for the domain model layer. Cheers for your help.

Comment: it is an anti pattern. I agree. thats why my suggestion is to inject everything. you could also use property injection if you want to avoid servicelocation and di, but in my view property injection breaks some pretty big oo design rules

Comment: I think this is one of the least documented and explained features in Ninject.  We need to have some docs that show what a good pattern is for using Modules, especially in n-tiered apps (i.e., multi-projects).

I would love not to have to add a Ninject nuget package to all my projects, just so I can keep modules within their logical domain boundaries.

For the time being, I just have a big ol' RegisterServices, with lots of BindTo's, and no modules.  This keeps all my projects free from a DI implementation, and my Web project can do the heavy lifting with Ninject at startup.  Comments?

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer refers to the `Scan()` method from `Ninject.Extensions.Conventions`.  Ninject 3.0 replaced this with a more powerful fluent interface for doing dynamic assembly binding.

```
    kernel.Bind(x => x
        .FromAssembliesMatching("*")
        .SelectAllClasses()
        .BindDefaultInterface());
```

The adventure continues at the [extension's Wiki](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions/wiki/Overview).

Comment: FYI: You have to add using to using Ninject.Extensions.Conventions; to get the FromAssembliesMatching extension method.